# Cannot remove the newly added items from a jQuery sortable list 2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
<div class="add">Click me to add new item to list</div>
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="delete">
        <div class="item">these old items can be removed by click on <span class="delBtn">DEL</span></div>
    </li>
    <li class="delete">
        <div class="item">these old items can be removed by click on <span class="delBtn">DEL</span></div>
    </li>
    <li class="delete">
        <div class="item">these old items can be removed by click on <span class="delBtn">DEL</span></div>
    </li>
</ul>


$("#sortable").sortable();

$(".add").click(function () {
    var newItem = '<li class="delete"><div class="item">these <span class="red">new items cannot be removed</span> by click on <span class="delBtn">DEL</span></div></li>';
    $("#sortable").append(newItem);
});

$("#sortable").delegate('.delBtn', 'click', function() {
  alert("A click happened, it was captured at #commonParent and this alert ran");      
});
```

instead of alert, I woud like to remove the list item...
please help me, how can I do that?!

you can [try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/MvnEv/110/)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `.on` instead:

```
$("#sortable").sortable();

$(".add").click(function () {
    var newItem = '<li class="delete"><div class="item">these <span class="red">new items cannot be removed</span> by click on <span class="delBtn">DEL</span></div></li>';
    $("#sortable").append(newItem);
});

$("#sortable").on('click','.delBtn', function() {
   $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MvnEv/111/

Comment: THX! that's worx... (I've tried that before... but obviously I did something wrong... NOW IT'S working!)

Answer (score 0):

well, if you are using jquery1.6+ , use on instead of delegate..

```
$("#sortable").on('click','.delBtn', function() {
   alert("A click happened, it was captured at #commonParent and this alert ran"); 
   $(this).parents('.delete').remove();
    //or
   $(this).closest('.delete').remove();
});
```

and `remove()` to remove it from the DOM.

`parents()` or `closest()` selector to select the `li` element

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/MvnEv/113/)

Comment: sorry... this solution removes only "this" which refers to <span class="delBtn">DEL</span> :-(

Comment: well.. i have updated my answer..i think you saw it while i was updating the answer. try it now.. :)

Comment: THX! your new answer is fine, this one works :-) THX again! This is a great community...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$("#sortable").sortable();

$(".add").click(function () {
    var newItem = '<li class="delete"><div class="item">these <span class="red">new items cannot be removed</span> by click on <span class="delBtn">DEL</span></div></li>';
    $("#sortable").append(newItem);
});

$("#sortable").delegate('.delBtn', 'click', function() {
  $(this).closest("div").remove();
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MvnEv/112/)